# Add Content-Type JSON header in .NET Core

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core

I use `return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));` to return JSON by my code and this work fine but content type is `text/plain`

when I use `[Produces("application/json")]` in my api response be like this:

```
{\"Value\":\"value1\"}
```

I need use json serialize, but also need content type `application/json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you manually serialize the response to json, the framework actually thinks that you are sending a string as response and will therefore add the content type header `text/plain` to the response. Therefore do not manually serialize the response object.

The easiest way to send objects as json is just to trust the default OutputFormatter which is set to [JsonOutputFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.jsonoutputformatter?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to do the work. It will serialize all outgoing object responses to json if no other content type is defined on the controller/method/action.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    ...your logic
    return Ok(res);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If your serialize a string, best to use (as pointed by Marcus)

```
return Ok(model)
```

The return type when using `Ok` method though depends on who your ASP.NET Core application is configured and which formatters are installed (by default only Json Formatter, but you could also install an Xml formatter) and which type the browser prefers. If the browser requests xml and you have xml formatter installed, it will return xml. If the browser requests json and json formatter is installed, it will return json. Otherwise fall back to whatever best suits.

If your data is already serialized as string (cause it comes from DB, filesystem etc.), use

```
return Content(jsonData, "application/json");
```

If your data is a file, just use

```
return PhysicalFile("my.json", "application/json");
```

If it's a stream

```
return File(fileStream, "application/json");
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

To return Json with the correct content type, return a JsonResult from your method, and then return a JsonResult like this:

```
// GET: api/authors
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json(_authorRepository.List());
}
```

For more information, check this article: [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: i should return like this "return Ok()"

Comment: Could you explain one thing? *Why?*

Comment: Also: have you looked at the article I linked to? Because there's quite a few scenario's in there.